# Measure pulse width generated in one pulse mode using HAL

Tags: measurement, pulse

I need to generate pulse in one pulse mode and measure width of this pulse using HAL. I'm using STM32F446RE board. I managed to configure timer to generate pulse but I have no idea how to implement pulse measurement. I found that it can be achieved with input capture but i couldn't find any example.

Here is my timer config:

```
void MX_TIM5_Init( uint32_t timerPrescaler, uint32_t timerPeriod, double timerPulse)
{
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;

  htim5.Instance = TIM5;
  htim5.Init.Prescaler = timerPrescaler;
  htim5.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim5.Init.Period = timerPeriod;
  htim5.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim5, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim5, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = timerPulse;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim5, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TIMING;
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim5, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim5);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in [the STM32F446xx Reference Manual in section 18.3.6](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00135183.pdf).  It uses one timer to capture the time of the rising edge and another to capture the time of the falling edge.  This mode is typically used to decode a PWM encoded input.

[image]

[image]